# How to get first datastore name of virtual maschine from powercli

Tags: powershell, scripting, vmware, powercli

I am making some script and i have a problem. Lets say i have 2 VM on ESXi first vm name is VM1 and the second is VM2.

VM1 is located on one datastore named DISK1,
VM2 is located on two datastores named DISK2 and DISK3

When i run powercli and connect to server and start a command like

`((get-vm "NAMEofVM" | Get-Datastore | Select-Object -Property name)[0]).name`

If i replace "NAMEofVM" by VM1 result will be

```
DISK1
```

if i replace "NAMEofVM" by VM2 result will be

```
    Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.
At line:1 char:66
+ ((get-vm VM2 | Get-Datastore | Select-Object -Property name)[ <<<< 0]).na
me
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

How to resolve it ? I want get only first datastore not all of them.

Comment: What about this then `get-vm "NAMEofVM" | Get-Datastore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name -First 1`? That should work regardless of how many datastores are returned. I feel like your example only has one datastore so it did not return an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Works.

`(get-vm "NAMEodVM" | Get-Datastore | Select-Object -Property name -First 1).name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you are having an issue since it is possible that `Get-Datastore` could return only a single element and the type listed in the error supports that `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`. Instead of trying to index into the array with `[0]` we could use `Select-Object` to do the work

```
Get-VM "NAMEofVM" | Get-Datastore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name -First 1
```

Or, like you said, this is an option that is a little more terse. If you are doing it this way specifying `-Property` would be redundant.

```
(get-vm "NAMEodVM" | Get-Datastore | Select-Object -First 1).name
```